# Keep item at a fixed position when scrolling in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a feature similar to `StickyHeaders` but not to that extent.
What I'm trying to do is to keep only **one** item (the first one) from being scrolled out of view. I tried set its `Y` property upon scrolling but it doesn't work as expected.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                recyclerView.getChildAt(0).setY(120);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add your first cell outside your recyclerview.
It would probably be the easiest way to solve your problem.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    ...>
    <include layout="@layout/your_first_cell"/>
    <RecyclerView .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need the said item to be scrolled along the viewport but not out of it. But your solution could also work.